# Replacing an image

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am trying to add or replace an image in an existing PDF file using iTextSharp. The file has 3 layers which are required by the printing company. The content on these layers cannot be merged.

Thus far I have tried many of the code examples (most don't seem to be in C# and can't find the conversion from java). The closest example is:

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(this.FrontPDFFile);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(this.OutputDirectory, FileMode.Create));
var pdfContentBuffer = stamper.GetOverContent(1);

// get image from our api
System.Drawing.Image image = GenerateQRCode("GUOIO", 1000, 1000);

// convert to itextsharp image and insert
iTextSharp.text.Image img = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(image, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE);
img.SetAbsolutePosition(100, 100);
img.ScaleToFit(100, 100);
pdfContentBuffer.AddImage(img, true);

stamper.Close();
```

This generates the pdf with the image on, however opening in Illustrator it is not shown, this is likely to be something to do with layers (I am told). Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Are you perhaps using the Adobe Illustrator "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" option when creating the PDF?

Comment: @ChrisHaas I had the same problem and after your comment I unchecked "Preserve Illustrator Editing Capabilities" option while creating the original pdf and now I can see the added image when I open the newly created pdf in Illustrator:) Do you think the spot colors I have in the original pdf will still work in the printer?